# Move Child Node to Parent Node On Condition

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an xml file from which I need to move/copy specific child node which has trade item id like **childA** to parent node by creating an empty parent node.

Like  **Input** **XML :**

```
<root>
<Payload>
        <TradeItemVersion>
            <TradeItemID>A</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>B</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>C</ProductID>
       <TradeItemVersion>  
     <Child>
            <TradeItemID>ChildA</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>Child</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>Child</ProductID>
       <Child> 
<Child>
            <TradeItemID>ChildB</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>Child</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>Child</ProductID>
       <Child>
<Payload>
<root>
```

**Final Output :**

```
<root>
<Payload>
<TradeItemVersion>
            <TradeItemID>ChildA</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>Child</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>Child</ProductID>
       <TradeItemVersion> 
        <TradeItemVersion>
            <TradeItemID>A</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>B</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>C</ProductID>
       <TradeItemVersion>  
<Child>
            <TradeItemID>ChildB</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>Child</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>Child</ProductID>
       <Child>

<Payload>
<root>
```

I was able to copy child at top but all **childs** are getting copied and I am not able to select specific child, Also I couldn't create new empty parent tag to put child inside it.

My code is below :

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TradeItemVersion">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="search"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Child"/>
    <xsl:template match="Child" mode="search">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="search"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself after lots of hit and trial.

Following XSL would convert :

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TradeItemVersion">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="search"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Child"/>
    <xsl:template match="Child[contains(TradeItemID,'ChildA')]" mode="search">
        <TradeItemVersion>
<xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</TradeItemVersion>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="search"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML :

```
<root>
<Payload>
        <TradeItemVersion>
            <TradeItemID>A</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>B</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>C</ProductID>

     <Child>
            <TradeItemID>ChildA</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>Child</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>Child</ProductID>
       </Child> 
<Child>
            <TradeItemID>ChildB</TradeItemID>
            <TradeItemTitle>Child</TradeItemTitle>
            <ProductID>Child</ProductID>
       </Child>
</TradeItemVersion>
</Payload>
</root>
```

Output XML :

```
<root>
  <Payload>
    <TradeItemVersion>
      <Child>
        <TradeItemID>ChildA</TradeItemID>
        <TradeItemTitle>Child</TradeItemTitle>
        <ProductID>Child</ProductID>
      </Child>
    </TradeItemVersion>
    <TradeItemVersion>
      <TradeItemID>A</TradeItemID>
      <TradeItemTitle>B</TradeItemTitle>
      <ProductID>C</ProductID>
    </TradeItemVersion>
  </Payload>
</root>
```